# getting errors on python using Mac OS X

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to coding
I started with python.. everything is going well except with something I couldn't find the answer to
I installed python 3.8.6 and sublime text on my Mac
whenever I try to run this code:

```
    magicians = ['Alex', 'mike', 'alisa']
     for magician in magicians:
  print(f"{magician.title()}, that was a great trick!")
```

I get syntax error > `print(f"{magician.title()}, that was a great trick!")`

when I do it on windows 10 it works fine no errors at all.. any idea what's wrong?
thanks!

Comment: That depends on python version, f-string appears in python3.6, you may have a lower verison

Comment: I use python 3.8.6

Comment: Show us the full Error traceback! And fix the indentation of your code!

Comment: I don't see any other issue. This definitely is a version issue. You think you might be running 3.8.6, but it might be running on an older version you might have installed before.